# What is the correct port forwarding rules for Panasonic Media Centre / TV Anytime to work

Tags: port-forwarding, media-center

I am trying to set up our Panasonic recorder to be viewable outside the local network.  It works fine within.  Without any rules, it does not work at all.  Without the final UDP rule, everything works - the programs are shown, but playback fails with `connection failed` error.

The [rules are here](https://av.jpn.support.panasonic.com/support/global/cs/av/mediacenter/faq.html)

| Server IP Address | Protocol | Port |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 114.179.237.36 | TCP | 48443 |
| 114.179.237.36 | TCP | 48501~48502 |
| 114.179.237.129 | TCP | 47808 |
| 114.179.237.23 | TCP | 47825 |
| 114.179.237.54 | TCP | 49000~49030 |
| 114.179.237.55 | TCP | 49000~49030 |
| any | TCP | 443 |
| any | UDP | Any |

I have set them up as

[image]

I have a few problems with the final UDP rule

1. It is too wide.  Any port at all !!!!
2. My router Ubiquiti UDM-Pro does not allow wildcard port numbers

If I put in ports 1-65000 for the UDP rule, then I can playback.

**Does anyone know the limited range of ports for the UDP for this usage ?**

Note, this is to connect to my computer,  just from outside the local network.

Comment: You can use something like Wireshark to identify the port.

Comment: Are you sure those are _"port forwarding"_ (incoming DNAT) rules? The page makes it sound like those are only used for _outgoing_ connections. (And your UDM doesn't even filter outgoing connections by default.)

Comment: @u1686_grawity, Without the rules, it doe snot work outside the local network. SO I am sure.  As mentioned, without the UDP rule, I can look at the list of files, playback fails.  So, that is another indication that these are for incoming rules.  Playback only works with the UDP rule in.

Comment: @RohitGupta - What did your Wireshark analysis show?

Comment: I havent had time to to install and run it yet.  Busy packing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that only UDP port 1900 is used.  I tested it a few times.  Without the UDP port, it will show the list of recorded items, but will not play them.

On searching for it's usage, it is assigned for `SSDP - Simple Service Discovery Protocol for the discovery of UPnP devices`.

References

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers)

[Speedguide](https://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=1900)

> The Simple Service Discovery Protocol (SSDP) is a network protocol based on the Internet protocol suite for advertisement and discovery of network services and presence information. It accomplishes this without assistance of server-based configuration mechanisms, such as Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCP) or Domain Name System (DNS), and without special static configuration of a network host. SSDP is the basis of the discovery protocol of Universal Plug and Play (UPnP) and is intended for use in residential or small office environments